# accessing data from method after it was initialized- vuejs

Tags: vue.js

When i try to access the data outside of the setter method, it returns null. Here is my code:

```
<div id="app">
     {{userLocation.lat}},
     {{userLocation.lng}},
     {{userLocation.acc}},
     {{userLocation.msg}}
     <button v-on:click="accessData">Show direction</button>
 </div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function(){ 
    return{
        userLocation:{
        lat:null,
        lng:null,
        acc:null,
        msg:''
      }
    }

  },
  created(){
    this.saveData();
    this.accessData();
  },

  methods: {

    saveData: function(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setPosition,function(){console.log("error")});
        }
    },

    setPosition: function(position){
            this.userLocation.lat=position.coords.latitude;
            this.userLocation.lng=position.coords.longitude;
            this.userLocation.acc=position.coords.accuracy;
            this.userLocation.msg="success";


    },

     accessData: function(){
            //shows null
            console.log(this.userLocation.lat);
    }

  }
})
```

if i call "accessData" inside "saveData" then the attribute shows correctly.
the same happens in the template or when i clicked the button.

Seems like when i call accessData, the variable is not defined yet, or is only accesible in the scope of the function. How can i access to userLocation without calling saveData everytime?

full example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Bulywyf/0227xyen/

Comment: In your fiddle the setPosition function is never executed

Comment: What do you mean? putting console.log("something") inside setPosition shows me the message fine. https://jsfiddle.net/Bulywyf/cmkdL63v/

Answer (score 0):

It shows `null` because your saveData() function does not actually call setPosition(). It only passes it as a callback, to be called later (e.g. after the user has accepted the pop-up to allow access to location data.)

Comment: i need the manner to know when the data is ready to be accessible from anywhere. what do you recommend to do?